# ExpressionEngine: Sort channel listing by Related Entry

Tags: sorting, expressionengine

Can someone help me in sorting a channel listing by Related entry title please?

I have a channel '**teams**' which has a field team_region which depends on another channel '**regions**'.

My code is as follows:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="teams" orderby="" sort="asc" limit="10"}
    <tr>
          <td>{title}</td>
          <td>{team_address}</td>
          <td>{related_entries id="team_region"}{title}{/related_entries}</td>
    </tr>
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

I want to Sort the result by '**team_region >> title**'. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thank You!

Comment: I just found a Note in expressionengine documentation:
"Ordering by a Relationship field will cause entries to appear in the order the relationships were made, not based on any content from the related entries."
I think its not possible. :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not take the opposite approach - start with the Regions channel, then use [reverse related entries](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/reverse_related_entries.html) to list your teams. Add a query tag to grab the region's title from within the `{reverse_related_entries}` loop, and you should be good to go:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="regions" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
{reverse_related_entries orderby="title" sort="asc" channel="teams"}
    <tr>
        <td>{title}</td>
        <td>{team_address}</td>
        <td>{exp:query sql="SELECT title as region_title FROM exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN exp_relationships r ON r.rel_child_id = t.entry_id WHERE r.rel_id = {team_region} LIMIT 1"}{region_title}{/exp:query}</td>
    </tr>
{/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) from Pixel and Tonic. It's a powerful multi-relational tool with tons more options than the built-in relationships field.

You'll probably want to use something like

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="channelname" orderby="title"}
```

[Link to docs →](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates)